# Stylesheet being loaded outside of <head>

Tags: media, css, html5

Wordpress (3.6) is loading two stylesheets (`mediaelement-css`, .../wp-includes/js/mediaelement/mediaelementplayer.min.css?ver=2.13.0 and `wp-mediaelement-css`, .../wp-includes/js/mediaelement/wp-mediaelement.css?ver=3.6) in wp_footer instead of wp_head. I'm getting an HTML5 error because they did not add the attribute property. I found out that this error always happens if a stylesheet is loaded outside of `<head>` without the attribute property. If it is loaded within  then it doesn't need the attribute property.

Is there a way of loading the two stylesheets in `<head>` instead of `<body>` to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 1):

The two stylesheets is only loaded when a video or sound was included in a post or page and that happens after wp_head.

But do not despair! There is a filter you can use! in the code it looks like this:

```
apply_filters( 'style_loader_tag', "<link rel='$rel' id='$handle-css' $title href='$href' type='text/css' media='$media' />\n", $handle );
```

so i wrote a function:

```
//add the filter
add_filter( "style_loader_tag", "change_css_links", 10, 2 );

// Function for the filter
function change_css_links($css, $handle){
    //load global styles to get src
    global $wp_styles;

    //check if it is the correct style
    if($handle == "mediaelement" || $handle == "wp-mediaelement"){
        //if it is: do awesome stuff
        // get all info for the css in array
        $css_info = $wp_styles->registered[$handle];

        //the array looks like this:
        /*
        [mediaelement] => _WP_Dependency Object
        (
            [handle] => mediaelement
            [src] => /wp-includes/js/mediaelement/mediaelementplayer.min.css
            [deps] => Array
                (
                )

            [ver] => 2.13.0
            [args] => 
            [extra] => Array
                (
                )

        )
        */
        // do the awesome
        $css = "your new and awesome link element!";
    }

    //return the new or old awesome!
    return $css;

}
```

Or you can deregister the styles and load them on every page.

Comment: Thank you for this solution and sorry I am a bit late with my answer! I tried to implement the function, but I have no idea how to go about setting up the array in within. Starting from `$css_info = ...` what is going on? Sorry for the question.

Comment: $css_info gets an array with the url and other information witch means that you can add or remove information from the link element. So maybe you wanna do this: $css = '<style scoped>@import url('.$css_info["src"].');</style>';to get a valid element.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a solution could be to add the following code to media.php or your functions.php:

```
function wp_mediaelement_scripts(){
    $library = apply_filters( 'wp_audio_shortcode_library', 'mediaelement' );
    if ( 'mediaelement' === $library && did_action( 'init' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-mediaelement' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-mediaelement' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_mediaelement_scripts' );
```

and comment out the following from functions wp_audio_shortcode() and wp_video_shortcode():

```
$library = apply_filters( 'wp_audio_shortcode_library', 'mediaelement' );
if ( 'mediaelement' === $library && did_action( 'init' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-mediaelement' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-mediaelement' );
}
```